# Most efficient way to implement matrix functions?

Tags: arrays, performance, julia

I've been trying for a while to figure out the **most efficient** way of handling a two dimensional array (i.e. a matrix) that contains a variable.
I construct a large matrix by concatenating smaller arrays, weighted with a variable. As a simplified example, this is what I currently do.

```
function myMatrix(x::Float64)
    M = vcat(hcat(x*A, C), hcat(C, 2*x*B))
    return M
end

const A = ones(2,2)  
const B = ones(2,2)
const C = zeros(2,2)
y_values = collect(0:0.01:10)

for y in y_values
    eivals, eivecs = eig(myMatrix(y))
    dosomething(eivals,eivecs) 
end
```

The problem: I have more (and more complex, non-diagonal) matrices and the final size is pretty large. At this moment, I call the function a few hundred times. Does anyone have a suggestion on what to do to make this process more efficient in terms of runtime?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The core problem aside, this is going to be super-slow because you're using non-constant globals inside `myMatrix`, which is (I think) the first no-no in the performance tips section of the official docs.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that.

Comment: I should mention that, in my original program, the matrices are actually depending on some earlier parts of the code, specifically on a few input parameters (that are set once for every program run). However, I followed the performance tips there and declared them as global.

Comment: Make a preallocated version where you change values of some output variable that's passed in instead of creating a new matrix every time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you mean that, can you specify a bit?

Comment: I think the question in its current form is too confusing to provide a satisfactory answer. It's not obvious to me why you would want to keep adding `C` to other matrices inside your loop. I suspect you possibly shouldn't be using matrices at all here. Maybe you should be using your own type? Also, why does myMatrix return a single matrix `M`, but then when you call it in the loop, you assign the output to the tuple `(eivals, eivecs)`? (this just pulls out the first two elements from `M` and assigns it to these variables).

Comment: Because, as I wrote, it is just a simplified (minimal) version of my actual code. I construct non-diagonal matrices out of smaller parts (I do theoretical solid state physics, so I want to leave out the details on why and how). You can think of A,B and C as non-diagonal and non-trivial matrices, they are NOT redundant. What you pointed out was a mistake in my example, thanks for that. I need the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I looked up preallocation (didn't know that was a thing) and it seems like exactly what I am looking for. However, I don't understand everything. In the performance tips section, they write a method xinc!(A::Array{T}, x::T). In this method they set each entry manually. Is this required for preallocation? Because unfortunately as it stands now I can't do this, I'm really depending on a loop where I construct A with hcat's and vcat's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution, using preallocation as proposed somewhere in the comments, does not solve my problem directly (because of the way I construct the matrices) but it may still be useful for some people reading this. Also I don't guarantee for the initially used statement of "most efficient", as this seems to widely depend on your purposes, size of the matrices and so on. The method is also mentioned in the Performance Tips section of Julia.

Because there has been some confusion, consider the following example:

```
function myMatrix(x::Float64)
    M = vcat(hcat(x*A, C), hcat(D, 2*x*B))
    return M
end

function doSomething(A::Array{Float64,2})
    nothing
end

const ArraySize = 1000
const A = ones(ArraySize,ArraySize)  
const B = ones(ArraySize,ArraySize)
const C = rand(ArraySize,ArraySize)
const D = rand(ArraySize,ArraySize)


for i = 1:1000
    ret = myMatrix( convert(Float64,i) )
    doSomething(ret)
end
```

This does literally nothing but construct a BlockMatrix(function) from initial matrices depending on one parameter. I was thinking this repeated construction is redundant and indeed, one can preallocate the memory for the matrix by writing:

```
function xinc!(ret::Array{T,2}, x::T) where T
    ret[1:ArraySize, 1:ArraySize] = x*A
    ret[1:ArraySize, ArraySize+1:2*ArraySize] = C
    ret[ArraySize+1:2*ArraySize, 1:ArraySize] = D
    ret[ArraySize+1:2*ArraySize, ArraySize+1:2*ArraySize] = 2*x*B
    nothing
end

function doSomething(A::Array{Float64,2})
    nothing
end

const ArraySize = 1000
const A = ones(ArraySize,ArraySize)  
const B = ones(ArraySize,ArraySize)
const C = rand(ArraySize,ArraySize)
const D = rand(ArraySize,ArraySize)



ret = Array{Float64}(2*ArraySize, 2*ArraySize)
for i = 1:1000
    xinc!(ret, convert(Float64,i))
    doSomething(ret)
end
```

For me, the second code executes in 9.866s while the first takes up 38.076s.

Edit: In response to the previous comment, if i write

```
function xinc!(ret::Array{T,2}, x::T) where T
    ret = [x*A  C
            D   2*x*B]
    nothing
end
```

the code takes 16.173s to execute. I don't know why, but this way of assigning the matrix is substantially slower.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Based on the comment below, this does not answer the question.

Do you mean constructing the Matrix? One way of doing that which is ideomatic is to use a block Matrix:

```
M = [x*A   C
    C    2x*B]
```

Not sure if that's the most efficient in terms of runtime, sorry.

Comment: No I'm fine with constructing the matrix (I think at least). My problem is that I do the concatenation process (i.e. the function call) a few hundred times and it seems a little idiotic. The matrices I'm constructing are constructed out of a few hundred smaller matrices, not just four like here, so I cant write them out explicitly like you did. I was hoping there might be a more computationally efficient way to go on about this matrix as function of x instead of basically constructing the matrix repeatedly for every x value.